# How to add music to ipad Music-app from iCloud-drive

Tags: ipad, audio, music, ios

I have uploaded all my music and epubs to iCloud-drive in different folders.

For books to be added to iBooks I had to select one book at a time and then select option *Copy to iBooks* and now the books are appearing in **iBooks**.

Similarly I tried for my audios which plays from iCloud-drive app but I don't see any similar feature to add it to the Music app library so that I can use the features of the Music app like playlists and all. Also I don't see any option in Music-app to add music from iCloud-drive.

I am using latest *iPad with iOS-11*.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add music to the iOS Music app directly, you need to add it to iTunes an a Mac or PC and sync from there. Or look for an alternative Music player in the store which may allow such things.